# ArcGIS API for Flex create customised widget

Tags: arcgis-flex-api, widget, flash-builder

I want to create customised widget using ArcGIS API for flex (in adobe flash builder). I surfed internet and all the samples I found of widgets use ArcGIS viewer for flex. Has anybody has the experience on creating widget using adobe flash builder? where should I start?

I am using Adobe Flex SDK 4.6 and ArcGIS API for Flex 3.6, thanks.

Comment: I added a [tag:flash-builder] tag to your question which should link you through to some Q&As here as a place to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with your custom widget, you need

- `ArcGIS for Flexviewer3.6` source code
- `ArcGIS API 3.6 for Flex`.

You can download

- `Flexviewer3.6` source code from [GitHub](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-viewer-flex/archive/3.6-src.zip).
- `AcrGIS API 3.6 for Flex` from [esri](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/) under **ArcGIS API for Flex** section.

Steps to import the source code to Flash Builder:

1. `Flash Builder` -> `File` -> `Import Flash Builder Project`.
2. Browse to downloaded source code zip file and `Open` the file.
3. Give name to project. (optional)
4. Click `Finish`.

Steps to add ArcGIS API to your flexveiwer:

1. Extract the `arcgis_api_for_flex_3_6.zip` file.
2. Copy the file `ArcGIS_Flex\libs\agslib-3.6-2013-12-13.swc` from extracted folder.
3. Go to Flash Builder and expand the imported flexveiwer project.
4. Paste the file in `libs` folder under flexveiwer project.

Now you are good to go.

you can add ArcGIS API to your flexveiwer from `Flex Build Path` too but above mentioned steps are simpler.

Comment: @ppLily As an alternative to receiving thanks as a comment I suspect most answerers would rather see their answer accepted (click green tick next to it) and/or upvoted